# How do I onmouseover in a <tr> check to see if a key was pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large table with a lot of data. Basically I'm trying to check, if a letter was pressed while someone was hovering over a `<tr>`. What I'm trying to do is basically blackout on the whole screen except for the hovered row when someone presses the letter f so that it can basically just focus on that row. Easier to see in the midst of a lot of data.

Here's what I have so far. Don't know if I'm in the right direction, but it's not detecting me pressing the letter. Also, if they press f again or esc or click outside of the row, I'd like it to go back to normal.

```
$(function(){

  $('#report tr').on('mouseover',function(){
    $('#report tr').removeClass('sel');
    $(this).addClass('sel');

    $(this).keypress(function(event){
      if(event==70){
        alert('hello');
      }
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: This is actually quite broad question, I'd say even too broad considering the current attemp. If you could accept a CTRL (SHIFT or ALT as well) instead of `f`, the task would be far more simple. Also, it's important to know, how large is the table? Hundreds of rows? Thousands? Are there child elements within `td`s or is the content always plain text? How are `td`s styled? How about the "blackout", is setting background of the `body` to black enough, or have you thought to use cover elements?

Comment: If you have any ideas on how to do the blackout portion, i'm open for suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
 $(function () {
        $('#report tr').hover(
            function () {
                $(this).addClass('sel');
            },function(){
                $(this).removeClass('sel')
            });

        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 102) //if they pressed f
                //do something with the selected item 
        });
    });
```

Basically, just attaching the keypress event to the document instead of trying to attach it to a specific element inside your hover function.

Edit:  Here's another possibility based on your comment.  Note that you would need to add a way to remove the sel class as well:

```
    $(function () {
        var currentElement;
        $('#report tr').hover(
            function () {
                currentElement = $(this); 
            });

        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 102) //if they pressed f
                currentElement.addClass('sel');
        });
    });
```

Comment: I see what you did there, but it's not really working the way i need it to work. I need to basically press f and the row i'm on highlights or something. I can't seem to get that going :\

Comment: I guess the sel isn't really working for me, i need to add sel to what ever i'm currently hovering over if i press f, but since pressing f is independent of the hover, how do i know which row to add sel to if i press f?

Comment: You could keep track of the currently hovered row in a variable and then add the class when the button is clicked instead.  I edited my answer to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, as to why `$('#report tr')` does not receive the `keypress` event:

> A keypress event handler can be attached to any element, but the event is only sent to the element that has the focus.

(https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

However you cannot simply give focus to `$('#report tr')` with `$('#report tr').focus()`:

> The focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus. This event is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form elements (, , etc.) and links (). In recent browser versions, the event can be extended to include all element types by explicitly setting the element's tabindex property.

(https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

If you wish to give `$('#report tr')` focus you will need to set a `tabindex` on your `$('#report tr')` elements.

An example of how this may be implemented:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pass keypress event to TR</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr tabindex="1">
                <td>data 1</td>
                <td>data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr tabindex="2">
                <td>data 3</td>
                <td>data 4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $rows = $('table tr');
                $rows.keypress(function(e) {
                    if (e.which == 102) {
                        $(this).css('background-color', '#ff0000');
                    }
                });
                $rows.on('mouseover', function(e) {
                    $(this).focus();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're right with `keypress`, but please notice, that OP has "a large table with a lot of data". Maybe there's hundreds even thousands of rows, and it's really not wise to add an event listener to every row. And you're adding even more listeners, every time a row is hovered, one more `keypress` is added, at some point the page will choke ...

Comment: I've updated the example with the `keypress` handler now being added only once per row as oppose to each time a row is hovered. But I agree this technique is perhaps not the one to use for a large dataset; I wanted to illustrate why the `keypress` handling wasn't working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet doing pretty much what you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentRow = null,           // Stores the currently hovered TR
        fKey = false,                // Indicates, if F has been pressed
        table = $('#table'),         // Holder for the table
        stopBlackout = function () { // Removes "blackout"
            $('body').removeClass('blackout');
            if (currentRow) {
                currentRow.removeClass('hilite');
            }
        },
         // Starts "blackout"
        startBlackout = function (row) { // row = row element
            row.addClass('hilite');
            $('body').addClass('blackout');
            if (currentRow[0] !== row[0]) { // Remove hilite if different row only
                currentRow.removeClass('hilite');
            }
            currentRow = row;
        },
         // Keydown listener toggles "blackout"
        toggleBlackout = function (e) { // e = event object
            if ('form' in e.target) {return;} // Exit if a form element is active
            if (e.which === 27 || e.which === 70) { // Action when hit Esc or F only
                fKey = !fKey;
                if (e.which === 27) {
                    fKey = false;
                }
                if (!fKey) {
                    stopBlackout();
                } else if (currentRow) { // Start "blackout" when having a hovered row
                    startBlackout(currentRow);
                }
            }
        };
    table.mouseenter(function () { // Activate table to receive key presses
        this.focus();
    });
    table.mouseleave(function () { // End "blackout" and stop receiving keypresses
        stopBlackout();
        table.blur();
    });
    table.keydown(toggleBlackout);
    table.mouseover(function (e) { // Highlight active row according to mouse hover
        var row = $(e.target);
        if (row[0].tagName !== 'TR') { // Usually TD or other element triggers mouseover
            row = row.closest('tr'); // Set target to TR
            if (!row.length) {return;} // Exit if e.target was TBODY or TABLE
            if (fKey) {
                startBlackout(row);
            }
            currentRow = row; // Update the currently hovered row holder
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.blackout {
    background: #000000;
}
.hilite {
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" tabindex="-1">
    <tr><td>R1<b>C</b>1</td><td>R1C2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R1C2</td><td>R2C2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R1C3</td><td>R3C2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R1C4</td><td>R4C2</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Some explanations**

All events have been attached to the table element, not to it's children. This reduces event listeners on the page and makes it faster, especially if the table is very large. The table must exist before adding these listeners, but you can add content afterwards.

`keydown` is used, since <kbd>Esc</kbd> doesn't fire `keypress` in all browsers. `fKey` variable in the code indicates, whether "blackout" is on or off.

The activate key (<kbd>F</kbd>) works only when hovering over the table, but not when any form element is active.

`mouseover` is fired every time the mouse is moved from an element to another within a `tr`, hence its handler has some extra checkings.

`mouseenter` handler makes the table to receive key presses automatically when hovered over it, no need to click to activate table first.

`mouseleave` handler stops table to receive key presses, and removes the "blackout".

`tabindex` of the table is set to `-1` to make the table to be able to receive focus, but putting it out of tabbing order.